# How to apply css for local scope without iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am developing a application for drag and drop at here: (without iframe)

https://cdn.rawgit.com/haonx/landingpage-builder/develop/index.html

Now, I use iframe for feature preview but inner document (iframe) cannot detect type (and information) of dragging object from outer document. `Placeholers` is not show. And texts is allowed drop to `Image dropzone`. (Expected is not)

I included scripts in both iframe and outer document here:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/haonx/landingpage-builder/feature/instant-preview/index.html
but border for droppable zone is not show

I tried iframe because its css is local scope. And it display styles correct.

Is any solution alternative for embed document with local styles? Or a way to get object information when drag it over iframe (for show placeholder which droppable)? I tried ng-include, event drop but it not working

Comment: When I was developing something similar there was no problems with dragging items outside an iframe and droping them inside it. There was no problem if JS script resposible for 'drag and drop' was included both in main file and in file loaded in iframe. Maybe that's the solution- to include your script to both files

Comment: What about just using a html `section` with a specific css id. And all your css starts with #thatid ?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek yes, i included them, but  script in iframe cannot detect dragging object, Expected border of droppable zone (which object allowed to drop) is not show